# Convert \DateTimeImmutable to \DateTime

Tags: php, datetime

How can I convert a [`DateTimeImmutable`](http://php.net/manual/class.datetimeimmutable.php) object into a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/class.datetime.php) object?

Comment: If you want to do this because a method you wrote requires a `DateTime`, you can make it require a `DateTimeInterface` instead.

Answer (score 30):

There is a pull request for a `DateTime::createFromImmutable()` method in PHP. It had been integrated ([1](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/300tib/datetimecreatefromimmutable_method_php_7_merged/?st=iyac0id6&sh=8342be48), [2](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/1145)), just to be [removed](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/2d9399af3514189375f34610acc33a34de44d772) later for no reason. Now it seems to be back in, but only for PHP 7.3 and higher.

So this is probably the easiest way right now:

```
$dateTime = new \DateTime();
$dateTime->setTimestamp($dateTimeImmutable->getTimestamp());
```

If you need to include timezone information:

```
$dateTime = new \DateTime(null, $dateTimeImmutable->getTimezone());
$dateTime->setTimestamp($dateTimeImmutable->getTimestamp());
```

Comment: I would `new \DateTime($immutable->format(\DateTime::ATOM))`. This is neat and least data loss (timezone etc) I can imagine at the moment.

Comment: Note that this will discard the microseconds, which are available since PHP 7.1.

Comment: I guess @AdrianFöder's solution is the best. Note that you should do `new \DateTime('now', $dateTimeImmutable->getTimezone());`. It doesn't accept null as a first argument.

Comment: It does accept null. It's one of the official examples, under `Example #2 Intricacies of DateTime::__construct()`: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php I think the Parameters section of this doc is wrong. The example could instead be wrong, but it's probably widely used enough that it would be better to update the spec than to disallow it.

Answer (score 19):

To convert with proper timezone:

For PHP >= 7.3

```php
DateTime::createFromImmutable(dateTimeImmutable);
```

For PHP <= 7.2

```php
DateTime::createFromFormat(
   DateTimeInterface::ATOM, 
   $dateTimeImmutable->format(DateTimeInterface::ATOM)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as a one-liner:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime("@{$dateTimeImmutable->getTimeStamp()}");
```

Comment: It could be done in more simple way: ```$dateTime = (new DateTime())->setTimestamp($dateTimeImmutable->getTimeStamp());```

Comment: Such an expression in a string is less verbose and code analysis features typically not undestand it, so code inspection features wont work. Also it might be slower due to string expression parsing however I doubt it makes sensible difference. Btw I found better alternative:
`$dateTime = new DateTime('@'.$dateTimeImmutable->getTimestamp());`